# What esperanto word should we use for moderator?

Tags: discussion

It would be nice to have some sort of consensus over what word we use in Esperanto for the moderators. Some suggestions:

- In Reddit apparently people say *kontrolanto*. This is also the suggestion on [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=moderator). It could be good to use the same terminology as Reddit, but I find this word very strange because *kontroli* is a purely passive action (like checking) and doesn't contain the meaning of moderating.
- I guess a direct translation of moderate could be *moderigi* so a moderator could be *moderiganto*. This seems kind of long so maybe an alternative could be *moderulo*.
- [John Well's dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) suggests *prezidanto* or *gvidanto* but these seem like very bad translations to me because they imply the person is taking control and leading rather than just doing administrative tasks.

Comment: This is a question about the language, not the site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was specifically asking about the terminology we should use on this site (for example, in the comments) rather than a general word. Even in English there would be many words that StackExchange could have chosen (operator, administrator etc) but it's important to use one word consistently throughout the site. So I was just hoping to extend that same consistency to discussions in Esperanto too.

Comment: Questions on this site should be in English. Knowing how to moderate a site doesn't require knowing other languages other than English.

Answer (score 1):

*To moderate* is *to calm*, and a *moderator* keeps the site calm, so I suggest *trankvilestro*.

Comment: "Trankvilestro" ŝajnas esti speco de trankvila estro